# How to Score a Perfect on Google Page Speed Insights

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I am working to speed up my site https://www.gscode.in/ and I have used Google Page Speed Insights for a report. Part of this report shows me that 'Google/Doubleclick Ads' is slowing the site down, see screenshot attached:

[image: Google PageSpeed Insights screenshot]

How can I solve this?

Comment: The PSI tool is already hinting you on how to improve that: "**Limit the number of redundant third-party providers** and **try to load third-party code after your page has primarily finished loading.**" The [Learn more](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/loading-third-party-javascript/) link you're seeing there explains in detail what the issue is and includes suggestions on how to fix it / improve it. Have you read that yet?

Comment: You can't solve it at this moment. As report says the source is AdSense JS and ads. You have no control over them beside removing ads altogether. AdSense ads just don't play well with Page Speed Insights and should be optimized.